# Dealing with jQuery parseHTML() and html() when using Google closure compiler,,,

Tags: javascript, jquery, casting, google-closure-compiler

I have a simple set of statements that actually work (I have run that code and it does what I expect of it) that looks as follow:

```
result_xml = result.jqxhr.responseXML;
a = jQuery("data[name='calendar']", result_xml).text();
new_calendar = jQuery.parseHTML(a);
jQuery("div.calendar").html(jQuery("div.calendar table.calendar-table", new_calendar));
```

`result` comes from an AJAX reply, you should recognize the `jqxhr` field.

I expect `a` to be a string since I get a block of data with `text()`. The data is an HTML string that I saved in the XML document. So I can cast it this way:

```
a = /** @type {string} */ jQuery("data[name='calendar']", result_xml).text();
```

Now I convert that string to an HTML DOM thinking it would be an Element:

```
new_calendar = /** @type {Element} */ jQuery.parseHTML(a);
```

And that's where I get this weird error:

> WARNING - invalid cast - must be a subtype or supertype
>   from: (Array.<(Element|null)>|null)
>   to  : (Element|null)

So `parseHTML()` would be returning an array of elements (or null)?

Then I was trying to use the output of the `parseHTML()` in the `html()` function and there too, I have a hard time to understand what is going on.

> WARNING - invalid cast - must be a subtype or supertype
>   found   : (Array.<(Element|null)>|null)
>   required: (Document|Element|Object.|jQuery|null|undefined)

Frankly, I do not see why the Google compiler makes it such that the output of one function cannot be the input of another, even if it works just fine in the real world.

Would an array of `Element` be considered a `Document`?

Then finally (yeah! all of that for 3 lines of JavaScript!) I get another error in regard to the input of the `html()` function:

> WARNING - actual parameter 1 of jQuery.prototype.html does not match formal parameter
>   found   : jQuery
>   required: (function (number, string): ?|string|undefined)
>          jQuery("div.calendar").html(jQuery("div.calendar table.calendar-table", new_calendar));

Here too, it works in the real world... will the jQuery object automatically be converted to a string and then re-transformed to a set of tags to be added in my calendar?

Are all of these *normal limitations* of the closure compiler?

---

Based on Chad answer, I changed my code this way:

```
result_xml = result.jqxhr.responseXML;
a = /** @type {string} */ (jQuery("data[name='calendar']", result_xml).text());
new_calendar = jQuery.parseHTML(a);
jQuery("div.calendar").empty().append(jQuery("div.calendar table.calendar-table", new_calendar[0]));
```

1. I cast the `text()` output to string in closure;
2. I use element 0 of `new_calendar` instead of directly `new_calendar`.
3. I changed the `html()` with `empty().append()` since the `append()` function accepts a `jQuery` object as input

This makes the closure compiler happy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes Absolutely this is expected behavior. There are many things that "work" in JavaScript. Closure-compiler attempts to force good behavior when asked.

As for jQuery - these are the *normal* limitations of the published jQuery API. With jQuery the code often supports undocumented behaviors (like you are listing). However the jQuery team is free to change behaviors that are not documented at any time.

Closure-compiler warns you if you are not matching what is listed as the API spec (and [that definition](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/contrib/externs/jquery-1.9.js) is community maintained - so not always 100% right).

Here's the relevant specifications:

- [jQuery().html(string)](http://api.jquery.com/html/) - *A string of HTML to set as the content of each matched element*
- [jQuery.parseHTML('string')](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/) - *Returns: Array*

Answer (score 1):

I use DOM API instead of jQuery. 
There is a full HTML text in data.

```
// create DOM parser object
var dom_parser = new DOMParser();
// parse HTML into DOM document object
var doc = dom_parser.parseFromString(data , "text/html");
// doc.body.innerHTML = body part in text, not object
// <body> tag is stripped.
// append the body part into div with the id "contentsarea".
$("#contentsarea").empty().append(doc.body.innerHTML);
```